# Python script to click Enable / disable WiFi

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib

I want to create a simple python script, which will log into my routers website, turn off the wifi and then apply the changes and also do the oposite (turn On wifi and apply the changes), unfortunatelly my knowledge of html tagging and python is not good enough, so please help me :)

Here is what I have created so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import requests

my_url = 'http://router/WLG_adv.htm'
response = requests.get(my_url, auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('My_username', 'My_password'))
c = response.content
uClient = uReq(my_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(c)
rows = soup.findAll('tr')[4::5]
soup.find("button", "button-apply")
```

...thanks to that I am able to log into a proper page with credentials and get right code to manipulate with:

Here is "wifi enable check box part" ( I belive it's check_wifi_sche() )

```
[<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input checked="" name="enable_ap" onclick="check_wifi_sche()" type="checkbox" value="enable_ap"/> Enable Wireless Router Radio </td></tr>,   <tr>
<td colspan="2">
<div id="wifi_sche_div1">
<input name="wifi_onoff" type="checkbox" value="wifi_onoff"/> Turn off wireless signal by schedule 
</div>
</td>
</tr>, <tr><td colspan="2" height="12"><div style="background-image:url('liteblue.gif');width:100%"> </div></td></tr>, <tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input checked="" name="wsc_config" type="checkbox"/>
<font>  Keep Existing Wireless Settings  </font>
</td>
</tr>]
```

And here is "Apply button part":

```
>>> soup.find("button", "button-apply")

<button class="button-apply" name="Apply" onclick="buttonClick(this,'Apply');return checkData();" type="submit" value="Apply"> <span class="roundleft_apply">Apply <span class="apply-icon">    </span></span><span class="roundright_apply">   </span></button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use selenium it is suitable tool for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve this issue finally. Thanks for your tip Dev, that really helped.
So my task was to do simple script to enable / disable Wifi and click apply button for router NETGEAR WNR3500Lv2.

I am posting info how to do it if someone needs it :)
(notice that in router address line (you have to put your router credentials, where I have put X's and Y's.

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-                   
# Ranorex selocity do chrome'a               <<< Very helpful tool for chrome to extract paths from websites.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()   # Remember to have your chrome driver in $PATH (download driver from google)
base_url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYY@ROUTERS-IP-ADDRESS/WLG_adv.htm"            # Place your login:password here:
driver.get(base_url)

# Wifi click
wifi_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@name='enable_ap' and @value='enable_ap']")[0]
wifi_button.click()

# Apply click
apply_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='target']/table[@class='subhead2-table']//button[@name='Apply']/span[@class='roundleft_apply']")
apply_button.click()

# Closing page (don't worry, it will complete the task, even when it's closed fast.
driver.stop_client()
driver.close()
```